# Why should I use User secrets only in the Development environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have to save keys out of project and repository. For this, I want to use [User secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets). But it is written there,

> Call AddUserSecrets only when the app runs in the Development environment, as shown in the following example

And I can't understand or find a cause. Why can't I use it in the Production environment?

Answer (score 4):

You can find it in the link you provided to the User Secrets documentation:

> The Secret Manager tool doesn't encrypt the stored secrets and
>   shouldn't be treated as a trusted store. It's for development purposes
>   only. The keys and values are stored in a JSON configuration file in
>   the user profile directory.

Comment: I don't have a goal to store encrypted data on my current job. But if had it, I would store encrypted data locally somehow, `User secrets` for an example, and key for decrypting somewhere else. I did it at my previous job. But instead `User secrets` I used the serialized JSON file in the well-known directory.

Comment: You just have to be aware that data using User Secrets is stored in a user profile directory and not encrypted, if you don't any any security issues about that you're fine. Just be sure those secrets cannot be used to damage your system somehow.

Answer (score 4):

I think the short answer is that you probably could if you wanted to but that it is not what it is intended for.

My understanding is that the primary purpose of User Secrets is to keep credentials out of source control. In the days before GitHub and the cloud, most developers just stuck any and all credentials in the web.config and it was mostly ok. Then lots of people started using public repositories and AWS and all of a sudden https://www.zdnet.com/article/trufflehog-high-entropy-key-hunter-released-to-the-masses/

There are now a great many different tools out there for managing secrets, which one best suits your needs is a much harder question, but you could consider:

- Are you using access controlled source control?
- Are you cloud or on-prem for build and deploy?
- Who has read access to the live servers?
- How sensitive is the data you are storing?
- What other applications are running on the server?

I was just poking around in the `CreateDefaultBuilder` method and found this, which is perhaps relevant:

```
if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(new 
              AssemblyName(hostingEnvironment.ApplicationName));

    if (assembly != (Assembly) null)
          config.AddUserSecrets(assembly, true);
 }
```

Obviously you don't have to use the default version and you could add secrets for all the environments, but there it is.

Answer (score 3):

This is a development time only tool. Storing any kind of secret in a file is risky, because you may accidentally check it in. In production, you can for example use environment variables to hold secrets (or any other more secure mechanism.)

While environment variables are one of the most used options in web development there are some reasons why this may not be the best approach:

1.The environment is implicitly available to the process and it's hard to track access. As a result, for example, you may face with situation when your error report will contain your secrets

2.The whole environment is passed down to child processes (if not explicitly filtered). So your secret keys are implicitly made available to any 3rd-party tools that may be used.

All this are one of the reasons why products like [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/use-cases/) become popular nowadays.

So, you may use environment variables, but be aware.

Answer (score 1):

User secrets are basically a `JSOn` File somewhere in your user directory. That works well on your dev pc. But on a production system, the values should usually be injected through more production ready configuration system(s), like `Environment Variables`, `appsettings.json` or a `azure keyvault`. `Envs` and `appsettings` are already activated per default.

Comment: I don't see any problems to add json file to `APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<user_secrets_id>\secrets.json` on server. And about using `Environment Variables`. If I will use it on the server, where is a profit of using `User secrets` on dev? It will be easier to use the same system on dev pc.

Comment: @Nodon The problem is one of security and one of conventions. "Normally" a production system is configured through some sort of defined process, e.g. a build task executing a script. That is usually executed on the production system as a different user than your user running the app. If you mix that, you get potential security holes. 
Even if you need user configs, you should add a json path manually to your providers and not use UserSecrets,

Comment: @Nodon Also, the secrets file has a guid - but that guid is static, try running multiple instances of youre app with different settings.

Comment: I will get an additional security problem with any technology If another user adds keys to `Environment variables` every time on deploying. Because key will be stored on the product machine and some deploying system storage. It's more secure to do one-time manually. I don't have a task to run multiple instances with different settings. But if I had it, I would use the command line. No one of  `Environment Variables`, `appsettings.json`, `User secrets` can't give such a possibility. I don't know anything about Azure, I don't use it.